# How to read Apache Cocoon 2.1 handle Json request body

Tags: json, apache-cocoon

If the request is url-encoded, I can get the request parameter pairs using xsp or xsl. But when I send a application/json request, I could not read the request body.

The [Cocoon request API](https://cocoon.apache.org/2.1/apidocs/org/apache/cocoon/environment/Request.html) doesn't support getReader() interface, thus read the request body as stream is also impossible.
I found a [similar question](http://cocoon.10839.n7.nabble.com/Accessing-application-json-message-body-of-POST-request-td58329.html) , the answer mentioned **text generator** , which is the one it meant to be in [cocoon generator page](https://cocoon.apache.org/2.1/userdocs/generators.html)?

```
The key request info I can get in cocoon is: 
Header information [name] : Content-Length
Header information [value] : 838
Header information [name] : Content-Type
Header information [value] : application/json
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, someone else using Cocoon 2.1!

I don't usually look for questions on Cocoon on SO, and just happened to stumble across this.

I hope I understood your question correctly.
Here are some suggestions, if it is still relevant:

- Use the [StreamGenerator](https://wiki.apache.org/cocoon/StreamGenerator)
- Compose the request in your generator and transform it using the [SparqlTransformer](https://github.com/nverwer/cocooncomponents/blob/master/src/org/apache/cocoon/transformation/SparqlTransformer.java), which does way more than just SPARQL.

You can transform the result with the [XSLT JSON parser](https://github.com/joepjoosten/xslt-json-parser) to get XML from your JSON.
In one of my applications, I have a pipeline like this:

```
      <!-- Retrieve a list of documents.
        Request parameters:
          start (optional): The index of the first document, default is 0.
          length (optional): The maximum number of results in the list, default is 100.
      -->
      <map:match pattern="doclist">
        <map:generate type="request"/>
        <map:transform src="xsl/request_to_doclist-query.xslt">
          <map:parameter name="default-start" value="0"/>
          <map:parameter name="default-length" value="100"/>
        </map:transform>
        <map:transform type="sparql"/>
        <map:transform src="xsl/json-parser.xslt"/>
        <map:serialize type="xml"/>
      </map:match>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's very smart solution! For me eventually I made a xsp basically wrote some Java code to handle the request. ATM, I'm expecting new cocoon version to be released which support piping REST type API:s. :-)